# Electric Heater Design

Tags: resistors, heat

Is creating an electric heater really as simple as creating a resistor and connecting a power source? I feel like it shouldn't be that simple.

Part of the reason is what values of resistors to use. My guess is you want them to be a few kilo-ohms as if they are to small you have the equivalent effect of shorting a battery (or power source). Then you can use the voltage to control the rate (P = V^2\R).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's that simple. Of course, if you make poor choices, you can also create a smoke, light and/or sound generator (single operation for those, usually.)

The vast majority of electric heaters are operated from fixed voltages at fixed power. Naturally, if you choose a resistor with inadequate power rating, it will tend to the smoke generator end of the spectrum.

A typical 500W at 240VAC baseboard heater will be about 115 ohms. The larger size of standard electric cookstove elements is about 25 ohms.

Control in most applications is full on or full off. Something like an electric stove control does not "turn down the voltage" - it adjusts how much time the burner is on .vs. how much time it's off. That can be done at very high speeds to get fairly precise control.

Comment: using a material with a high heat capacity will also help keep the temperature stable when using on-off cycles

Answer (score 2):

It is that simple. A heater is a resistor attached directly to your power pins. The only thing special about that resistor is that it can dissipate huge amount of power without getting destroyed (unlike your puny little resistors which you use for making small circuits).

Calculations for making one are quite simple. You just need to know the operating voltage and the heating power that you want. Let's say you are using 220V line and want 1 kW heater.

R = V*V/P = 220*220/1000 ohms = 48.4 ohms

However since 220V can go up to 250V in some cases, so let's take a safer value of 250*250/1000 = 62.5 ohms.

Now all you need to do is to find a resistor of 62.5 ohms (or higher) which can dissipate 1 kW of power without melting/burning.

The downside of this higher resistance is that you won't be getting 1 kW at 220V. You will be getting 774 watts only.

A better alternative is to find 48.4 ohms resistor that can tolerate 1291 watts of power so that if voltage goes up, the heater still keeps working.

If you try to get curious and use small 60 ohms (approx) resistor that you use for making circuits, you will see a flash and some smoke and a dead resistor. Reason: They had enough resistance but couldn't handle that much power dissipation. They are usually 0.25 watt resistors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, resistive electrical heating is simply a resistance dissipating power from flowing current through it.  There are several factors that must be considered when selecting the resistance value. Perhaps the most important is how much power is available from the source. Something that operates on utility mains power is a much different design than something that operates on coin batteries or photo-voltaic (solar) cells.  You must also consider how quickly you need to change the temperature, how much space you have, what is the "thermal load" or thermal mass of what you are trying to heat, etc.